# Candidates of nonsmoothable homology 4-spheres

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

I'm not trying to duplicate a question [Are there non-smoothable homotopy/homology spheres?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236029/are-there-non-smoothable-homotopy-homology-spheres)
But in Igor Belegradek's answer, he pointed out that "Some of them (homology spheres) have large fundamental groups for which 4-dimensional surgery is not yet known to work. It seems smoothability of such spheres is open." So I wonder

> Are there any explicit constructions regarding those candidates?